# While building GCC 8.5.0: "error: `CC' has changed since the previous run"

Tags: c, linux, gcc, build-error, libgcc

I'm building GCC 8.5.0 on a Devuan Chimaera GNU/Linux system (using GCC 10). I've configured with `./configure --disable-gnat`, then ran `make`. At some point, I get:

```
echo timestamp > s-selftest-c
rm gcc.pod
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc'
Checking multilib configuration for libgcc...
Configuring stage 1 in x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
configure: error: `CC' has changed since the previous run:
configure:   former value:  `/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/opt/gcc-8.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/opt/gcc-8.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /opt/gcc-8.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /opt/gcc-8.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   '
configure:   current value: `/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   '
configure: error: in `/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: changes in the environment can compromise the build
configure: error: run `make distclean' and/or `rm ./config.cache' and start over
make[2]: *** [Makefile:18716: configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:24352: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0'
make: *** [Makefile:945: all] Error 2
```

Why is this happening? I tried `make distclean` and repeating the process, but it didn't help.

Comment: It loks like you configured in the source directory.  This is not recommended.

Comment: @stark: What _is_ recommended?

Comment: Following the directions:  http://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Comment: To perform a (wholly) out-of-source build, which is what the docs recommend, create a build directory outside the source directory, make that the current working directory, and run GCC's `configure` script from there.  That would be something like `../gcc_src/configure --option1 ...`.  Run `make` from the same place.  Support for such out-of-source building is standard in GNU build systems, but how strongly devs recommend exercising that alternative varies.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the in-source building is related to the problem, but since you're having trouble, changing to an out-of-source build is a good place to start.

Comment: Example configuring gcc-8.5.0 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ynCtdCJFZEUgtfjuuQuiRSG8W_m1rFhm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen: Can you put that someplace more publicly accessible?

Comment: "more publicly accessible" : Any suggestions ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen: I meant something like pastebin. But I understand what you mean and will try this today.

Answer (score 0):

GCC build prerequisites ...

```
# apt install g++ autoconf libtool gawk flex bison binutils-dev libelf-dev texinfo zlib1g-dev
```

Example configuring gcc-8.5.0

```
tar xvf gcc-8.5.0.tar.xz 
cd gcc-8.5.0/

tar xvf mpfr-4.0.2.tar.xz && mv -v mpfr-4.0.2 mpfr
tar xvf gmp-6.1.2.tar.xz && mv -v gmp-6.1.2 gmp
tar xvf mpc-1.1.0.tar.gz && mv -v mpc-1.1.0 mpc

cd ../
mkdir build-gcc850
cd build-gcc850/

export CC=gcc73 CXX=g++73 && \
../gcc-8.5.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc85 \
--program-suffix=85 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran \
--disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-system-zlib
```